# How to set dynamic ssh output to zsh variable?

Tags: zsh

I would like to set a variable to the output of a ssh command in zsh. The ssh command itself connects to a first server, then ssh again from this server to a second server where I want to execute my command.

Here is the command (works fine when typed in the shell) :

```
ssh -t host1 "ssh -t host2 "uname -a""
```

I have an ssh key setup for host1, so the connection doesn't ask for a password. I don't have one for the subsequent connection between host1 and host2, so I have to type the password.

Now, I would like to save the content of `uname` in a variable, to be used in my zsh script. I naively tried :

```
a=$(ssh -t host1 "ssh -t host2 "uname -a"")
```

but it seems to hang forever, somehow the interactive password login prompt is not redirected to me. If I try a `echo $a` afterwards I got a `user@host2's password:'` to confirm it

My guess is that something went wrong in the way zsh handles quotes and double quotes, but I could not figure out what. I've tried many variations, without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely not related to quoting (which *should* probably be `ssh -t host1 "ssh -t host2 \"uname -a\""`). Quotes only apply to the command-line arguments, not to the command input/output. Only `$()` can affect the output.

The problem might be simply how `ssh` handles tty input/output. It seems that `ssh` (here `ssh -t host1`) does *not* use the client-side terminal device even if it has one available – it writes to stdout instead, which `$()` will capture.

---

The best solution would be to set up key authentication between *local* and *host2*, then add your keys to ssh-agent, and use the "Agent forwarding" option: `ssh -A host1 ssh host2 uname -a`. This way you don't need to copy your private key anywhere else.

Comment: Thanks. I cannot manually set key authentication between local and host2 (actually, the whole point of the script I'm trying to write was to automate this). I didn't know about the -A option either, and I finally found an alternative solution : executing my script directly from host1. Thanks for the pointers !